# Write specific columns of files into another files, Who can give me a more concise solution?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a troublesome problem about writing specific columns of the file into another file, more details are I have the file1 like below, I need to write the first columns exclude the first row to file2 with one line and separated with '|' sign. And now I have a solution by sed and awk, this missing last step inserts into the top of file2, even though I still believe there should be some more concise solution on account of powerful of awk、sed, etc. So, Who can offer me another more concise script?

```
sed '1d;s/ .//' ./file1 | awk '{printf "%s|", $1; }' | awk '{if (NR != 0) {print substr($1, 1, length($1) - 1)}}'
```

file1:

```
col_name    data_type   comment
aaa         string     null
bbb         int     null
ccc         int     null
```

file2:

```
xxx   ccc(whatever is this)
```

The result of file2 should be this :

```
aaa|bbb|ccc
xxx   ccc(whatever is this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's no whitespace in the column 1 data, in increasing length:

```sh
sed -i "1i$(awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' file1 | paste -sd '|')" file2
```

or

```sh
ed file2 <<END
1i
$(awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' file1 | paste -sd '|')
.
wq
END
```

or

```sh
{ awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' file1 | paste -sd '|'; cat file2; } | sponge file2
```

or

```sh
mapfile -t lines < <(tail -n +2 file1)
col1=( "${lines[@]%%[[:blank:]]*}" )
new=$(IFS='|'; echo "${col1[*]}"; cat file2)
echo "$new" > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning awk at the moment.

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=""} {if(NR>1) a = a $1 "|"} END{a=substr(a, 1, length(a)-1); print a}' file1
```

Edit: Here's another version that uses an array:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {a[++n]=$1} END{for(i=1; i<=n; ++i){if(i>1) printf("|"); printf("%s", a[i])} printf("\n")}' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/[^\n]*\n//;s/\(\S*\).*/\1/mg;y/\n/|/;s/|$/\n/;r file2' file1
```

Process file1 *"wholemeal"* by using the `-z` command line option.

Remove the first line.

Remove all columns other than the first.

Replace newlines by `|`'s

Replace the last `|` by a newline.

Append file2.

---

Alternative using just command line utils:

```
tail +2 file1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | paste -s -d'|' | cat - file2
```

Tail file1 from line 2 onwards.

Using the results from the tail command, isolate the first column using a space as the column delimiter.

Using the results from the cut command, serialize each line into one, delimited by `|`',s.

Using the results from the paste, append file2 using the cat command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Awk script to merge the files as per your spec.

```sh
awk '# From the first file, merge all lines except the first
NR == FNR { if (FNR > 1) { printf "%s%s", sep, $1; sep = "|"; } next }
# We are in the second file; add a newline after data from first file
FNR == 1 { printf "\n" }
# Simply print all lines from file2
1' file1 file2
```

The `NR==FNR` condition is true when we are reading the first input file: The overall line number `NR` is equal to the line number within the current file `FNR`. The final `1` is a common idiom for printing all input lines which make it this far into the script (the `next` in the first block prevent lines from the first file to reaching this far).

For conciseness, you can remove the comments.

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR { if (FNR > 1) { printf "%s%s", sep, $1; sep = "|"; } next }
FNR == 1 { printf "\n" } 1' file1 file2
```

Generally speaking, Awk can do everything `sed` can do, so piping `sed` into Awk (or vice versa) is nearly always a [useless use of `sed`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).